# Tutorials for connecting ListView in Mysql Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview, click

Can someone help me find a tutorial connecting ListView in Mysql and output it in ListView, im just a newbie on android...

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps that is needed to connect your listView with database.

First, ask yourself. Do you want to get the data from online database?

**YES** : You need to parse the result generated by your sql query and then read in your app. There can be 2 ways, either by JSON or XML. Sending and getting JSON/XML result can be done using some simple php code.

**NO :** Then you need to read up on : setting up SQLite database on ListView tutorials.
Here's a good one that i recommend : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I just want to get it on localhost not online thats why I want to use MySQL and for the purpose of client server application..

Comment: I think its possible with a http request, I think?

Comment: I guess you still have to communicate through PHP, you can follow the tutorial from : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
I used that for one of my project,

Comment: Yes, make HTTP request and get the result in either XML or JSON and parse it in your app

Comment: yes I have already made a connection with an android and Mysql by inputing data on the database, my problem now is to ouput it into a lsitview.

Comment: Can you get the result in either format already? XML or JSON?
How do you want to output it? Default listview can only show text. You can do your customAdapter to fit your purpose.

Comment: I found this tutorial (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/289191/Send-and-Recive-Parameter-with-Android-To-Mysql-PH)
but it made some errors..

Comment: here is what I made (http://www.mediafire.com/download/wf6woeyzpkipmcm/PHPAnd.rar)

Comment: @OrlandoGueseYansonJr. you shouldnt connect directly to your db.